# Flex: How to most effectively traverse a table column

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, actionscript

I have a table "template" which is used in various "instances". All instances have checkboxes in the second column (for record-delete).

What would be the most effective way of traversing the table and check if at least one checkbox is selected (to enable a "delete" button)?

Answer (score 0):

By table, do you mean DataGrid?

You'll need to store the "checked" state of each column in your dataProvider.  The DataGrid makes use of renderer recycling, so there is only a record of what is shown on the screen.

If you check something, and then scroll so that something yo checked is off screen; you'll have no record of what was checked.

Comment: Currently the column is linked to a datamodel field: editorDataField="cbSelected"

My question is,  how do i most effectively iterate over the datamodel in an eventlistener? Such as:

grid.getDatamodel
[now what?]

Comment: Just loop over that like you would look over anything else.  for (x = 0; x < dataProvider.length; x++){ do stuff to dataProvider[x] }